# Sinch clarification regarding relayRemotePushNotificationPayload:

Tags: ios, sinch

In the document it's stated that `[client relayLocalNotification:]` should be guarded with check `[client isStarted]`, but not mentioned in `[client relayRemotePushNotificationPayload:]` (I deliver the remote push notification payload through my own socket, not Apple push notification).

My questions are:

- Will `[client relayRemotePushNotificationPayload:]` invoke `start` automatically or i'd better check & buffer the payloads to be used in `clientDidStart` delegate message?
- It seems in the log that remote push notification payload is requested & generated multiple times when the remote user is not online. is it by design?
- Is it safe to call `[_client start]` multiple times?
- Should I call `[_client stop]` when my app goes to background? (I use my own socket to deliver remote push notification payload)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) `[client relayRemotePushNotificationPayload:]` will internally invoke `start` when it's passed a payload that requires the client to be started (eg a call).

2) If you have multiple instances (eg you have logged in on multiple devices) for the same user this is expected as they should have different push data.

3) Yes, calling `start` multiple times is safe.

4) Generally you should only call `stop` when the app is about to terminate, instead you can call `stopListeningOnActiveConnection` if you don't want the connection to be running in the background (and since you have implemented your own wake up mechanism).

Comment: when `[client relayRemotePushNotificationPayload:]` invoke `start`, the `clientDidStart:` delegate method will be called, right? thanks!

Comment: @wangii yes the delegate method will be invoked